# Error in EGIT in checkout from SpringSource repository

Tags: egit, springsource

I am using Eclipse GIT (EGIT) to check out from 
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase

After trying to clone the repository I am receiving the error:

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase /info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found

Please, check

Network Connection settings

Network Connection -> SSH2 Eclipse Preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by not having the latest version of git due to updates in the server-side application. I recommend trying to access it through a different protocol (git:// or ftp) if possible. Otherwise, just check for updates in the egit plugin.

Update:

I have learned for a fact that github supports the git protocol. You can use

`git://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase.git`

as the repository. (If egit asks for a protocol separately from the URL, change it from https to git).